# Apache2 SSL Configuration Issues

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I just got a PositiveSSL cert from Comodo and then followed the steps here

http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/04/04/installing-comodo-positive-ssl-certs-on-apache-and-openssl/

to setup Apache.  When I created the CSR I had specified mydomain.com as the FQDN.  However, when I restart Apache and examine the error logs I see the message

RSA certificate configured for example.com:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

openssl x509 -in server.crt -noout -subject

gives me the output

subject = /OU=Domain Control Vaidated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=example.com

My apache2.conf file contains

```
<VirtualHost ip:443>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.key
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example.com.cer
```

For good measure I have tried concatenating (in that order)

COMODORSADomainVaidationSecureServerCA.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt

on their own and also with (last) AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt.

It makes no difference.  I have to admit that I am fumbling in the dark here.  I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to help here.

Comment: You may wish to consider not redacting your domain name, and posting the certificate (**not** the private key!) here; it'll all help with diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I thought the etiquette here required redaction.  You mean I post the contents of the .crt file?

Comment: <grin> far from it - more data is always welcome, though [there is debate about how much is *required*](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/963/what-information-should-i-include-or-obfuscate-in-my-posts).  Yes, I do mean post the contents of the .crt file - SSL certificates are not a private matter, given as they are to every single person who ever makes an SSL connection to your server.

Comment: Thanks.  As it turns out I managed to fix this.  I had added the SSL cert info  to my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file.  I went and added the same info to the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf file, restarted Apache and it all worked. I should explain that a while ago I had added <VirtualHost IP:443(& 80)> directive to the apache2.conf file to keep out someone out there on BigDaddy who was merrily pointing his garbage domain to my IP.

Comment: @MadHatter I meant to add - by and large I get these things working by trial & error so if you can explain why the setup I now have works I would much appreciate it (and vote up your answer :-)

Comment: I'm guessing this is on ubuntu, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17503/discussion-between-droidos-and-madhatter).